# Joomla onPrepareContent event not triggering

Tags: events, caching, joomla, joomla1.5

I'm working on a Joomla plugin which utilises the `onPrepareContent()` event. However, I've determined that this event does **not** get dispatched if caching is enabled, and the content is cached (i.e. in `cache/com_content`).

How can I act on the viewing of an article, even if the article is cached, and have the article data available? (*I'm specifying that last condition because, otherwise, I could just use a system event - e.g. onAfterRoute() or similar*)

Answer (score 1):

the idea behind cache is indeed that the data is retrieved once and served many times, so it will not be available anywhere during a cache load; so in your plugin you *could* access the database and load the article using a different event such as onAfterRoute(), but of course you're slowing down your site, and possibly an ajax browser based alternative could achieve the same purpose (which you haven't clarified).

An alternative is to force Joomla not to cache the article if you only desire to achieve this on a limited number of articles, but this would most likely require a core hack and it wouldn't be faster than using the plugin as I wrote above.

Comment: I'm definitely wary of doing anything that will slow the site down. I've currently disabled the cache specifically for com_content, which is obviously going to incur a big hit, but this is a case in which the functionality *must* be present: it's access control.

Comment: wait, access control implies that you have different user groups and that any differences will affect them only after they login: but page cache is disabled for logged in users by default, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Some elements of my access control apply to not-logged-in users.

Comment: Ok my point is: the non-logged-in users, or guests, will all see the same: so the same cache will be fine for all of them; for everybody else, page cache will be disabled. This doesn't mean that the onPrepareContent() is not invoked: it's invoked once every cache refresh, default is 15 minutes.

Comment: Ok, but what I need is for some code to be executed every time an article is viewed (strictly, /attempted/ to be viewed), AND for that code to have visibility of the article. What's the best way of achieving that?

Comment: I'd say, stick with cache and see which plugin events fire, choose one, and you'll have the id parameter passed in so it won't be difficult to load the article either from db or using the com_content model or table.  Or, do it in javascript with an ajax callback if it's ok for your code to run after the article was viewed.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 3.4.0, I tried using system events in a content plugin, and they do not fire when the content is cached; only once, when the page is first loaded and cached. After that, they do not fire again. I guess the content plugin only gets invoked when the page is being cached, whatever events it contains.